# I want to import a css file in my jinja2 template page(flask)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

All my pages inherit from layout.html and i want to import different css files for each file like articles.html, login.html, dashboard.html etc.

I created a folder named as "static" in my project and created main.css in this folder.

Then I tried to import css file in articles.html but i can't import

Here is my codes in articles.html:

```html
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{‌{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
{% endblock head %}


{% block body %}


{% endblock body %}
```

And It's my file explorer page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyHB2.png)

Comment: Is your block "head" enclosed between ´<head>´ and ´</head>´ tags? The ´link´ entity is only valid between those tags.

Comment: Yes, my block enclosed between head tags

Comment: Have you ever found a way through?

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to add CSS directly in the child template.

```
    {% extends 'layout.html' %}

    {% block head %}

<style type="text/css">
    #upload {
        background: #b81c1c;
    }
</style>

    {% endblock head %}


    {% block body %}

<p id="upload">{{ form.text.label }} <br> {{ form.text(size=14) }} <br>

    {% endblock body %}
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to import a css file